# FParsec: how to combine parsers so that they will be matched in arbitrary order

Tags: f#, parser-combinators, fparsec

The task is find particular key-value pairs and parse them. The pairs can occur in any order. My partially working attempt:

```
open FParsec

type Parser<'a> = Parser<'a, unit>
type Status = Running | Done

type Job = 
    { Id: int
      Status: Status
      Count: int }

let ws = spaces

let jobId: Parser<int> = ws >>. skipStringCI "Job id" >>. ws >>. skipChar '=' >>. ws >>. pint32

let status: Parser<Status> = 
    ws >>. skipStringCI "Status" >>. ws >>. skipChar '=' >>. ws >>. (
        (skipStringCI "Running" >>% Running) <|> (skipStringCI "Done" >>% Done))

let count: Parser<int> = ws >>. skipStringCI "Count" >>. ws >>. skipChar '=' >>. ws >>. pint32

let parse: Parser<Job> = parse {
    do! skipCharsTillStringCI "Job id" false 1000
    let! id = jobId
    do! skipCharsTillStringCI "Status" false 1000
    let! status = status
    do! skipCharsTillStringCI "Count" false 1000
    let! count = count
    return { Id = id; Status = status; Count = count }}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let sample = """
Some irrelevant text.
Job id = 33
Some other text.
Status = Done
And another text.
Count = 10
Trailing text.
"""
    printfn "%A" (run parse sample)
    0
(* 
result:
 Success: {Id = 33;
 Status = Done;
 Count = 10;} 
*)
```

So, it works but it has two problems: obvious duplication ("Job id" in jobId function and "Job id" in the top-level parser and so on), and it expects "Job id", "Status" and "Count" to be sequenced in this particular order, which is wrong by the requirement.

I have a strong feeling that there's an elegant solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The first problem (duplication) can be solved with a minor refactoring. The basic idea is wrapping each parser into a wrapper that would do skipping.
**Note** that this code is yet far from perfection, I just tried to make refactoring as small as possible.

```
let jobId: Parser<int> = pint32

let status: Parser<Status> = 
    (skipStringCI "Running" >>% Running) <|> (skipStringCI "Done" >>% Done)

let count: Parser<int> = pint32

let skipAndParse prefix parser =
    skipCharsTillStringCI prefix false 1000
    >>. ws >>. skipStringCI prefix >>. ws >>. skipChar '=' >>. ws >>. parser

let parse: Parser<Job> = parse {
    let! id = skipAndParse "Job id" jobId
    let! status = skipAndParse "Status"  status
    let! count = skipAndParse "Count" count
    return { Id = id; Status = status; Count = count }}
```

---

The second problem is more complicated. If you want the data lines to appear in a free order, you must consider the case when

- **not all** data lines present;
- a certain data line appears **twice** or more;

To mitigate this, you need to produce a `list` of data lines found, analyze if everything required is there, and decide what to do with any possible duplicates.

Note that each data line can not afford to have "skip" part anymore, since it may skip an informative line before the actual parser.

```
let skipAndParse2 prefix parser =
    ws >>. skipStringCI prefix >>. ws >>. skipChar '=' >>. ws >>. parser

// Here, you create a DU that will say which data line was found
type Result =
    | Id of int
    | Status of Status
    | Count of int
    | Irrelevant of string

// here's a combinator parser
let parse2 =
    // list of possible data line parsers
    // Note they are intentionally reordered
    [
    skipAndParse2 "Count" count |>> Count
    skipAndParse2 "Status"  status |>> Status
    skipAndParse2 "Job id" jobId |>> Id
    // the trailing one would skip a line in case if it has not
    // been parsed by any of prior parsers
    // a guard rule is needed because of specifics of
    // restOfLine behavior at the end of input: namely, it would
    // succeed without consuming an input, which leads
    // to an infinite loop. Actually FParsec handles this and
    // raises an exception
    restOfLine true .>> notFollowedByEof |>> Irrelevant
    ]
    |> List.map attempt // each parser is optional
    |> choice // on each iteration, one of the parsers must succeed
    |> many // a loop
```

Running the code:

```
let sample = "
Some irrelevant text.\n\
Job id = 33\n\
Some other text.\n\
Status = Done\n\
And another text.\n\
Count = 10\n\
Trailing text.\n\
"

sample |> run parse2 |> printfn "%A "
```

will produce the following output:

```
Success: [Irrelevant ""; Irrelevant "Some irrelevant text."; Id 33;
Irrelevant ""; Irrelevant "Some other text."; Status Done; Irrelevant "";
Irrelevant "And another text."; Count 10; Irrelevant ""]
```

Further processing requires filtering `Irrelevant` elements, checking for duplicates or missing items, and forming the `Job` record, or raising errors.

---

UPDATE: a simple example of further processing to hide out `Result` and returning `Job option` instead:

```
// naive implementation of the record maker
// return Job option
// ignores duplicate fields (uses the first one)
// returns None if any field is missing
let MakeJob arguments =
    let a' =
        arguments
        |> List.filter (function |Irrelevant _ -> false | _ -> true)

    try
        let theId     = a' |> List.pick (function |Id x -> Some x | _ -> None)
        let theStatus = a' |> List.pick (function |Status x -> Some x | _ -> None)
        let theCount  = a' |> List.pick (function |Count x -> Some x | _ -> None)
        Some { Id=theId; Status = theStatus; Count = theCount }
    with
        | :?System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException -> None
```

To use it, simply add the following line to the code of `parse2`:

```
|>> MakeJob
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the second approach becomes a bit tadeus as we start to find concrete Results in the result list.

Comment: Thanks! However, the second approach becomes a bit tadeus as we start looking for concrete Results in the result list. So, I just run the lower-level parsers (for Job id, Status and Count) independently, convert the FParsec's Result to Choice and pipe them with Choice's bind (using a readerChoice {} CE from ExtCore for convenience).

Comment: Exposing `Result` DU is not a good idea, indeed. Further processing should be probably done in the same module. See the updated answer for a very naive function that would combine the elements and return a `Job option`.

Comment: Believe me or not, I did write the _same_ MakeJob function as yours just before I switched to the approach I described in the previous comment :) I think it's not so good to mix Id, Status and Count into a homogenous list and then pick them back, handling errors as we go... I still believe that run the parsers independently and then building a Job instance with Choice monad is a better approach. What's more, multiple "attempt"s do effectively the same thing: running each parser, then backtracking to the begin of the stream and so on.