# fparsec parsing key value pairs with different data types

Tags: f#, parser-combinators, fparsec

I'm trying to write a parser which can parse key value pairs which can vary on the value data type.

> KEY1:1,2,3
>
> KEY2:abc
>
> KEY3:123

With the following code

```
open FParsec
type UserState = unit
type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t,UserState>

let str s = pstring s 
let str_ws s = str s .>> spaces
let stringLiteral : Parser<_> = manyChars (noneOf "\">")

let numList : Parser<_> = sepBy1 (pint32) (str ",")  

let parseHeader inner header = str header >>. str ":" >>. inner
let parseKvps = 
    let strHeader header =  parseHeader stringLiteral header .>> newline  
    let numListHeader header = parseHeader numList header .>> newline 
    let numHeader header = parseHeader pint32 header .>> newline 

    let rest = parse {
        let! key1 = numListHeader "KEY1"
        let! key2 = strHeader "KEY2"
        let! key3 = numHeader "KEY3"
        return key1,key2,key3
    }
    rest

let kvps = "KEY1:1,2,3\nKEY2:abc\nKEY3:123"
run parseKvps kvps
```

Above gives the following error:

```
val it : ParserResult<(int32 list * string * int32),unit> =
  Failure:
Error in Ln: 3 Col: 9
KEY3:123
        ^
Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
Expecting: any char not in ‘">’ or newline
```

I think this has something to do with the `numList` parser because taking the first key out works as expected.

Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The third parser fails because FParsec did not find a required `\n` at the end.

There are several options to fix the problem:

1. Make your data valid by adding `\n` to the stream:

   ```
   let kvps = "KEY1:1,2,3\nKEY2:abc\nKEY3:123\n"
   ```

   Downside: modifying a source stream is only good for testing, not for the real app.
2. Make `.>> newline` optional:

   ```
   .>> (optional newline)
   ```

   Downside: It may lead to errors when two keys at the same source line are attempted to parse.
3. Try using `eof` as a possible alternative to `newline`

---

Also, a side note. Your code seems to be very hard to support. Think what happens if the keys occur in a wrong order in the source string, or a new key needs to be added over the course of your app development.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020840/974789) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31948386/974789) answers for more details.

Comment: adding the `\n` doesn't work unfortunately. I've tried that and keep getting the same error. It works fine if I remove the first key `KEY1`, something to do with the int list parser my guess. Just not sure how to figure it out.

Comment: @Pavel, your `stringLiteral` is also written inaccurately as it overflows the end of line. Did you mean `(restOfLine false)` instead?